# Find specific element in nested tuple

Tags: python

`deep_in` that takes in a tuple tup and an element elem and `returns True` if elem exist in tup and `False` otherwise.

```
def deep_in(tup, elem):
    for i in range(0, len(tup)+1):
        if elem == tup[i]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I can't return `True` for `deep_in(((),(),(3,)), 3)`

Comment: Can there be deeper nestings in the tuples?

Answer (score 1):

To handle arbitrarily nested tuples you could recurse to find nested elements:

```
def deep_in(tup, elem):
    for v in tup:
        if v == elem:
            return True
        if isinstance(v, tuple) and deep_in(v, elem):
            return True
    return False
```

or using [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
def deep_in(tup, elem):
    return any(deep_in(v, elem) if isinstance(v, tuple) else v == elem
               for v in tup)
```

Demo:

```
>>> def deep_in(tup, elem):
...     for v in tup:
...         if v == elem:
...             return True
...         if isinstance(v, tuple) and deep_in(v, elem):
...             return True
...     return False
... 
>>> deep_in(((),(),(3,)), 3)
True
>>> def deep_in(tup, elem):
...     return any(deep_in(v, elem) if isinstance(v, tuple) else v == elem
...                for v in tup)
... 
>>> deep_in(((),(),(3,)), 3)
True
```

Without recursion, just testing with `in` still requires that you don't use `return` early.

Your code makes that mistake; the first element in the tuple is not equal to `elem` triggers an immediate `return False`, without testing the rest of the tuple.

Your version can be fixed by using an `in` containment test, fixing the upper limit of the range and moving the `else:` branch out of the `for` loop; only return `False` when the loop has finished:

```
def deep_in(tup, elem):
    for i in range(len(tup)):
        if elem in tup[i]:
            return True
    return False
```

but you should just loop *directly* over the tuple instead of using a `range()`, and you could use `any()` here as well:

```
def deep_in(tup, elem):
    return any(elem in t for t in tup)
```